# Variadic Template Template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to create a base class that is a wrapper around std::array that overloads a bunch of common arithmetic operators. The end result will be sort of like std::valarray, but with static size.  I'm doing this because I am creating a whole host of child classes for my library that end up replicating this functionality. For example, I need to create a MyPixel class and a MyPoint class, both of which are essentially just statically sized arrays that I can perform arithmetic on.

My solution is to create a StaticValArray base class from which MyPoint and MyPixel can derive. However to disallow users from adding a MyPoint to a MyPixel, I'm using the CRTP pattern as such:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
struct promote
{
  typedef T1 type; // Assume there is a useful type promotion mechanism here
};

template<class T, size_t S, template<typename... A> class ChildClass>
class StaticValArray : public std::array<T,S>
{
  public:
    // Assume there are some conversion, etc. constructors here...

    template<class U>
    StaticValArray<typename promote<T,U>::type,S,ChildClass> operator+ 
        (StaticValArray<U,S,ChildClass> const & rhs)
    {
      StaticValArray<typename promote<T,U>::type,S,ChildClass> ret = *this;
      std::transform(this->begin(), this->end(),
          rhs.begin(), ret.begin(), std::plus<typename promote<T,U>::type>());
      return ret;
    }


    // More operators....
};
```

This is pretty cool, because the ChildClass can have any arbitrary class template parameters, and this thing will work. For example:

```
template<class T, class U>
class MyClassTwoTypes : public StaticValArray<T,3,MyClassTwoTypes>
{ };

template<class T, class U>
class MyClassTwoTypes2 : public StaticValArray<T,3,MyClassTwoTypes2>
{ };

int main()
{
  MyClassTwoTypes<int, float> p;
  MyClassTwoTypes<double, char> q;
  auto z = p + q;

  MyClassTwoTypes2<double, char> r;
  //  r += q;  // <-- Great! This correctly won't compile

  return 0;
}
```

My problem is this: I would like to stuff some ChildClass into the CRTP bit of StaticValArray that doesn't necessarily have just classes as its template parameters.  For example, consider this N-Dimensional Point class:

```
template<class T, size_t S>
class MyPointND : public StaticValArray<T,S,MyPointND>
{ };
```

This unfortunately won't compile, because size_t is not a typename - I get the compiler error:

```
type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T, long unsigned int S, template<class ... A> class ChildClass> class StaticValArray’
test.C:36:54: error:   expected a template of type ‘template<class ... A> class ChildClass’, got ‘template<class T, long unsigned int S> class MyPointND’
```

Is there any way to create a variadic template template parameter pack that can be absolutely anything (typenames, ints, size_t's, doubles, whatever?) because in the end I really don't care what the type is in there.  Note that I can't just fully specify ChildClass (e.g. `class MyPointND: public StaticValArray<T,S,MyPointND<T,S>>`) because this would break my type promotion mechanism.

Comment: Regarding the `promote` structure, you can take advantage of `decltype`: `typedef decltype(T+U) type;` within the structure.

Comment: My real promotion implementation does use this, I just call it "promote" to be clear. The details are left out here just for brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if, in place of the size_t, you used an std::integral_constant? You would embed the numerical value of the size of your array in it, and you could use it as a type.

**EDIT**

In order to reduce the verbosity, you could define your own integral constant class, something like:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct size_ : std::integral_constant<std::size_t,N> {};
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
MyPointND<int,size_<3>> x;
```

Comment: Hm, this seems to be in the right direction! Unfortunately, the instantiation of MyPointND gets a little chatty:  MyPointND<int, std::integral_constant<int,3>> x;

Comment: What you could do would be to create your own class deriving from std::integral (edited post above).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have a `traits` class, specialized for each type containing whatever you need for type promotion, and then pass in the complete type to the StaticValArray.

Moreover, with `decltype`, you shouldn't need anything like this- `decltype` will tell you what you get by adding a float and an int.

```
template<class U>
StaticValArray<decltype(*(T*)nullptr + *(U*)nullptr),S,ChildClass> operator+ 
    (StaticValArray<U,S,ChildClass> const & rhs)
{
  StaticValArray<decltype(*(T*)nullptr + *(U*)nullptr),S,ChildClass> ret = *this;
  std::transform(this->begin(), this->end(),
      rhs.begin(), ret.begin(), std::plus<decltype(*(T*)nullptr + *(U*)nullptr)>());
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something - can you elaborate a bit about the traits class?

Comment: DeadMG: wouldn't it be suitable to use std::declval in place of the casting and dereferencing nullptr?